# Main Menu Adding Buttons Not appearing

Tags: android, android-studio

So depending on the version of android studio I use, it comes with different templates. One comes with a main_menu.xml file which allows you to add items (buttons) to your main. Well, recently the template I had didnt come with the main_menu.xml so I manually added the .xml file and added my code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Hello" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_mainMenu2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:title="Main Menu"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" /> />

</menu>
```

My mainactivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_mainMenu2:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));

        case R.id.action_mainMenu:
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Sadly the menu wouldn't add any items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the **"xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"** which android studio recommends is wrong. Remove it and use android instead of app.

```
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Hello" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_mainMenu2"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_white_24dp"
    android:orderInCategory="10"
    android:title="Main Menu"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" /> />
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have overridden [onCreateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)). Referencing docs:

> Initialize the contents of the Activity's standard options menu. You should place your menu items in to menu. This is only called once, the first time the options menu is displayed. The default implementation populates the menu with standard system menu items.

Something like below should suffice:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.you_menu_file, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have upvoted you but it doesn't work. I have the oncreateoption but I do get 3 dots on the top right corner on  my menu which just shows my items as a tab

Comment: @SPete That is because you use `showAsAction` as `always` or `withRoom`. Please use `never` instead, if you don't want them to show like that and if you want them to show after clicking the 3 dots (the overflow menu icon).

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` lifecycle method, too. See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)) for more details.

Comment: I have upvoted you but it doesn't work. I have the oncreateoption but I do get 3 dots on the top right corner on  my menu which just shows my items as a tab.